# Samba server: file limit exceeded when creating folder

Tags: centos7, samba4

I have set up a Samba server to share a USB drive on my network.

I can see the drive, I can edit/delete every file, but I cannot create any because I get a `file size too large for the destination file system`. Also on the server, I can create a file just like I should be able to on Windows.

The trouble area is [HDD]. The device is mounted to the path folder. The device is a FAT32 filesystem. I tried setting `fstype` without much luck

The `smb.conf` looks as follows:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        netbios name = centos
        security = user

#       unix charset = UTF-8
#       dos charset = CP932

#       hosts allow = 10.8.0.0/16

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
[Anonymous]
        comment = Anonymous File Server Share
        path = /srv/shared/anonymous
        browsable =yes
        writable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        read only = no
[HDD]
        comment = 4TB USB HDD
        path = /media/usb/hdd
        browsable =yes
        writable = yes
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0755
        valid users = @backup
        write users = @backup
        guest ok = no
```